Can A xor (B and C) be transformed into SAT-XNF?
I'm trying to wrangle a problem into XOR-SAT, but I'm stuck with a couple of terms in the form of :
A xor (B and C)
Does any one knows if it is possible (or impossible for that matter) to turn them into viable XNF formula (i.e., XORs clauses joined by ANDs)?

It is impossible.  XNF formulas are a system of linear equations (linear over GF(2)).  "A xor (B and C)" is not linear.

Specifically, over $\mathbb F_2$, “A xor (B and C)” is the quadratic polynomial $A+BC$.
